# Extension methods not allowed in nested static classes?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nested-class

Why is this? I would find it *really* nice to be able to have some extension methods locked down to be used only within one of my classes. Don't really want to have certain extension methods available everywhere... and they look so much nicer than regular static methods :P

---

For clarification:

The reason I want these extension methods is because I am extending a Form, which has a DataGridView on it. And I am getting very tired of lines like these:

```
foreach(var row in grid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => (bool) r.Cells[checkBoxColumn.Index].Value))

foreach(var row in grid.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => (bool) r.Cells[checkBoxColumn.Index].Value))
```

Would like an extension method so that I could just do

```
foreach(var row in grid.Rows.CheckedRows())

foreach(var row in grid.SelectedRows.CheckedRows())
```

So in other words, this extension method would not be useful at all outside this class. But it would make the code a lot cleaner. Can of course make regular methods too, and that is what I ended up doing, since this wasn't possible.

Aaanyways, I was just curious to know if anyone had some good arguments to why they had chosen to put a restriction like this upon where extension methods can created used. *Must be in a static class* makes total sense. *Can't be in a nested static class* doesn't... to me at least...

Comment: Looks like none of these answers give a good technical reason why it cannot be done.

Comment: Like you, I much prefer the extension method syntax. SomeThing.HasSomeCondition() is superior to HasSomeCondition(SomeThing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using an extension method really make your code *a lot cleaner* than using a standard helper method on your class?

```
// extension method
foreach (var row in grid.Rows.CheckedRows())
foreach (var row in grid.SelectedRows.CheckedRows())

// standard helper method
foreach (var row in CheckedRows(grid.Rows))
foreach (var row in CheckedRows(grid.SelectedRows))
```

Comment: perhaps not. I just like it better when things are not backwards. kind of. Although, maybe I just need to adjust my thinking from "grid -> rows -> the checked ones" to "the checked ones of grid -> rows"... hmm... but I guess this kind of turns into a subjective coding style kind of thing now. Good point though! =) Will accept it as an answer, unless someone comes with some Microsoft related "the thought behind this" kind of thing.

Comment: @Svish (way later): it's not (purely) subjective: the non-extension systax composes poorly as is causes excessive nesting (i.e. poor readability).  the extension syntax is a form of reader-tailcalls, if you will :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you own the source code of the type, why are you using extension methods?  Why don't you just make those extension methods members of the type itself?

Extension methods are best used to extend types that you did not create.  While they are useful tools they are a layer of indirection that should be a last resort rather than a first.  While you can use them to extend your own types it makes more sense to reserve their use for types that you did not create.

Comment: Um, pretty sure he didn't create DataGridView ;-)

Comment: Hi Andrew. Can't agree with you on this.  In some cases it makes sense to decorate existing classes with additional functionality without making it widely available.  We could either derive, maybe create a decorator class or simply use extension methods and in some cases, extension methods help here.  Take Unity, LINQ itself and may others for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If you're extending a Type, then the extension methods should be as equaly accessible as the type itself.

Best practices also suggest putting all extension methods in one place, preferably in one static class or contained within a single namespace.

Comment: Putting all extension methods in one place is as bad idea as putting all utility methods in one place.

Comment: If you're extending a type, at no stage should extension methods be as accessible as the type surely?

Comment: I'm with the OP. It would be nice to limit the scope of your extension methods. Sometimes what you need to do with the type only applies in a specific scenario but you still want to take advantage of the syntatic sugar of extension methods.

Comment: Like @Eamon said, extensions provide a nice way of composing calls by _extending_ the functionality of some target type. If the feature forces you to make these extensions in a broader scope then you cannot use extensions (and everything nice they do) to extend the target with private functionality. Your choice is to make the functionality less private than your current design, or to not use the extension feature. If the feature provides a syntax that is useful, it is not logical that it is only useful when you extend the target type with non-private functionality.

Comment: BTW, +1 because I'm pretty sure your answer is the correct one from the point of view of the language designers.